# AWS Beanstalk and docker-compose, php-fpm, ignore database, proper deploy?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been looking it for at least few hours and I was unable to find a solution, so I would like to ask for your advice.

I have a `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  php:
    build:
      context: dev/php
      - ./source:/application

  nginx:
    build:
      context: dev/nginx
    depends_on:
      - php
    volumes:
      - ./source:/application
      - ./dev/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - "80:80"

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.22
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${RDS_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${RDS_DB_NAME}
      - MYSQL_USER=npuser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${RDS_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

and now I would like to deploy it using the proper way with CLI commands, so it could be done by CI/CD.

To do so - right now I'm doing the following:

1. cut the `mysql` and other databases part from docker-compose.yaml, as I would like to use RDS database
2. run `eb init`
3. run `eb deploy --staged`

What I don't like about this approach is point 1, where I need to modify the original `docker-compose.yaml` file, and point 3, where I need to add `--staged` because `docker-compose.yaml` changed in point 1.

Of course, I don't want to remove entirely mysql from `docker-compose.yaml` file, as I would like it to be easily run in local dev env, but I see no option in `eb` to deploy only selected containers.

Also, I was wondering, maybe I should use `Dockerrun.aws.json` instead of `docker-compose.yaml` for eb deploy? I hope you can get me to the right direction, as I have no idea what should be proper deploy in this scenario.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Did you find a solution?